# generate new random image after duplicate image is detected

Tags: javascript, html, random, duplicates

I am trying to create a quiz in which people rank 4 random images, using drag and drop to sort the images into their preference. Each image has to appear twice.

The same image can not appear twice in the same comparison (ie icon1, icon1, icon3, icon7) If the a duplicate random image is generated, a new image should be chosen. The duplicate image should not appear in the comparison.

The code I have recognises when duplicates appear, however, duplicates are still visible in the html.

It is the random image function that is causing the problem. I am in desperate need for help.

```js
function randomImageRank(){
      var images = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("images"));
      var practice = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("practice"));
    
      total = window.sessionStorage.getItem("total")
      count = total - ((JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("images")).length + JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("practice")).length) - 1);
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You are on image " + count + " of " + total;
      counter += 1


     random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
     random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
     random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
     random4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    
      var image1 = document.getElementById("drag1")
      var image2 = document.getElementById("drag2")
      var image3 = document.getElementById("drag3")
      var image4 = document.getElementById("drag4")
    
      if (practice.length > 0 ){
        image1.src = practice[0][0]
        image2.src = practice[0][1]
        image3.src = practice[0][2]
        image4.src = practice[0][3]
        practice.splice(0, 1)
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("practice", JSON.stringify(practice))
    } else {
        if (counter % 15 == 0 ) {
            image1.src = ("images/images/break_rank1.png")
            image2.src = ("images/images/break_rank2.png")
            image3.src = ("images/images/break_rank3.png")
            image4.src = ("images/images/break_rank4.png")
    } else {
        if (images.length == 0) {
            sendRank();
        } else { 
            if ((images[random1] == images[random2] ||  images[random1] == images[random3] || images[random1] == images[random4]  
                 || images[random2] == images[random4] || images[random3] == images[random2] ||images[random3] == images[random4])) {
            
                    rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
                    rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
                    rnd3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
                    rnd4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

                    random1 = rnd1
                    random2 = rnd2
                    random3 = rnd3
                    random4 = rnd4
            
                    image1.src = images[random1]
                    image2.src = images[random2]
                    image3.src = images[random3]
                    image4.src = images[random4]
            
                    console.log("duplicate")
                    
                } else {
                image1.src = images[random1]
                image2.src = images[random2]
                image3.src = images[random3]
                image4.src = images[random4]
                console.log("no duplicate")
            }
            }
         
         counter = counter + 1
         images.splice(random1, 1);
         images.splice(random2, 1);
         images.splice(random3, 1);
         images.splice(random4, 1);
         window.sessionStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(images))

        }
      }
    }
    
    

// Rank Website 
function startRank(){ 
    var practiceArray = new Array();
    practiceArray[0] = ["images/images/practice/practice1.jpg", "images/images/practice/practice2.jpg", "images/images/practice/practice4.jpg", "images/images/practice/practice7.jpg"]
    
    
    var imageArray = new Array();
    var imageArray = ["images/images/icon1.jpg", "images/images/icon2.jpg", "images/images/icon3.jpg", "images/images/icon4.jpg", "images/images/icon5.jpg", "images/images/icon6.jpg", "images/images/icon7.jpg",
    "images/images/icon8.jpg", "images/images/icon9.jpg", "images/images/icon10.jpg", "images/images/icon11.jpg","images/images/icon12.jpg", "images/images/icon13.jpg", 
    "images/images/icon14.jpg", "images/images/icon15.jpg","images/images/icon16.jpg", "images/images/icon17.jpg", "images/images/icon18.jpg", "images/images/icon19.jpg",
    "images/images/icon20.jpg", "images/images/icon21.jpg", "images/images/icon22.jpg", "images/images/icon23.jpg","images/images/icon24.jpg", "images/images/icon25.jpg", 
    "images/images/icon26.jpg", "images/images/icon27.jpg", "images/images/icon28.jpg", "images/images/icon29.jpg", "images/images/icon30.jpg", "images/images/icon31.jpg", "images/images/icon32.jpg", "images/images/icon33.jpg", "images/images/icon34.jpg",
    "images/images/icon35.jpg", "images/images/icon36.jpg", "images/images/icon37.jpg", "images/images/icon38.jpg", "images/images/icon39.jpg", "images/images/icon40.jpg","images/images/icon1.jpg", "images/images/icon2.jpg", "images/images/icon3.jpg", "images/images/icon4.jpg", "images/images/icon5.jpg", "images/images/icon6.jpg", "images/images/icon7.jpg",
    "images/images/icon8.jpg", "images/images/icon9.jpg", "images/images/icon10.jpg", "images/images/icon11.jpg","images/images/icon12.jpg", "images/images/icon13.jpg", 
    "images/images/icon14.jpg", "images/images/icon15.jpg","images/images/icon16.jpg", "images/images/icon17.jpg", "images/images/icon18.jpg", "images/images/icon19.jpg",
    "images/images/icon20.jpg", "images/images/icon21.jpg", "images/images/icon22.jpg", "images/images/icon23.jpg","images/images/icon24.jpg", "images/images/icon25.jpg", 
    "images/images/icon26.jpg", "images/images/icon27.jpg", "images/images/icon28.jpg", "images/images/icon29.jpg", "images/images/icon30.jpg", "images/images/icon31.jpg", "images/images/icon32.jpg", "images/images/icon33.jpg", "images/images/icon34.jpg",
    "images/images/icon35.jpg", "images/images/icon36.jpg", "images/images/icon37.jpg", "images/images/icon38.jpg", "images/images/icon39.jpg", "images/images/icon40.jpg" ]
    
    
    
    var ranked = {}
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("ranked", JSON.stringify(ranked));
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(imageArray));
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("practice", JSON.stringify(practiceArray));
    
    counter  = 0;
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
    
    total = (JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("images")).length + JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("practice")).length)
    count = total - ((JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("images")).length + JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("practice")).length) - 1);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("total", total)
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You are on image " + count + " of " + total;
    
    }
    
    // this returns the name of the picture eg image1
    function serialize () {
      var serialized = []
      var img = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]')
      img.forEach(image => {
      serialized.push(image.src.split('/').pop())
      })
      return serialized
    }
      
    // this allows you to sort the images using drag and drop
    var sorted = document.getElementById("rankedPicture")
    Sortable.create(sorted, {
    group: "rankedImages",
    onEnd: function(e) {
    console.log(serialize()) 
    },
    
    store: {
      // We keep the order of the list
      set: (sorted) => {
      var order = sorted.toArray ()
     // console.log(order)
      localStorage.setItem (sorted.options.group.name, order.join ('|'))
      },
    
      // We get the order of the list
      get: (sorted) => {
      var order = localStorage.getItem (sorted.options.group.name)
      return order? order.split ('|'): []
      }
      }
})
```

```html
<html> 

<head> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainstyle.css">
</head>

<h1> Rank the Icons from Most to Least Beautiful</h1>

  <h3> Drag and Drop the icons into position </h4>

    <hr>

  <body class="body" onload="startRank()"> 
    <div id="rankedPicture" class="imagesRank" style="width: 100%;">
  

        <img src="images/images/start_rank.png" data-id="1" id = "drag1" width="200px" height="100px">

        <img src="images/images/start_rank.png" data-id="2" id = "drag2" width="200px" height="100px"> 

        <img src="images/images/start_rank.png" data-id="3" id = "drag3" width="200px" height="100px"> 

        <img src="images/images/start_rank.png" data-id="4" id = "drag4" width="200px" height="100px"> 
  
    </div>

    <br>
    
    <br>
    
    <hr>
    <div class="buttonRank"> 
    <button type="button" onclick="storeRank()" style="height:50px;width:100px;font-size:medium;"> Submit</button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="counter" id=counter></div>
  </div>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your if block with a while loop

```js
while ((images[random1] == images[random2] ||  images[random1] == images[random3] || images[random1] == images[random4]  
        || images[random2] == images[random4] || images[random3] == images[random2] ||images[random3] == images[random4])) {
        
    rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    rnd3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    rnd4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

    random1 = rnd1
    random2 = rnd2
    random3 = rnd3
    random4 = rnd4

    console.log("duplicate")     
} 

image1.src = images[random1]
image2.src = images[random2]
image3.src = images[random3]
image4.src = images[random4]
console.log("no duplicate")
```

Comment: thank you!! when I use the while loop, it ensure that no two duplicate images are shown in the same comparison. However, each image appears more than twice (ie the splice is working how it is meant to) do you know why that would be?

Comment: you want to use slice, not splice - `The splice() method changes the original array`, so after you run it once, the indexes are are all changed.

Comment: would the splice method not have to be used? as the image has to be removed from the array so it does not appear again, then once no images are left in the array the ranking of images will stop?

Comment: I attempted to do it simultaneously so that the index. order will not have changed, **images.splice(random1, 1, random2, 1, random3, 1, random4, 1)**                             However, that did not work either

Comment: you can use the splice but you need to make sure that you do it so that the indexes for later ones don't change i.e .greatest one. at this point i think it'll be better to revisit your randomization picker logic - do it one by one 4 times (vs. doing all 4 in parallel), then when you splice you're only doing one splice and the next random (on a smaller array) guarantees a non-duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I think you have many code duplicates.
But below I show one of ways to randomize anything

```js
const someArray = ['a', 'b','с', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

const randomize  = () => {
    const temp = [... someArray]; // create copy
    someArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5); // shuffle
    console.log(someArray.slice(0, 4)) // get first 4 elements
}

randomize();
randomize();
randomize();
randomize();
```